# File-name not visible in the URL

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I am able to see the file name in the `URL` in lower environments like *SIT* and *UAT*. But in Production environment, some junk value is replacing the file name. Any help will be great.

File name is replaced with some junk value this -> `"bWFzdGVyfGltYWdlc3w4OTM1fGltYWdlL3BuZ3xpbWFnZXMvaDk4L2g4My84ODA0MTAxMDk1NDU0LnBuZ3xjMWY2OTZmOGQ5ZGM2MTIxMmQxMmUwODI5ZGQwYTg5YzNhMjIyYjQzMTJlMzc1MTU0ZmUyZWFjOGE5MjUyMGFj"`

Comment: Are you talking about media objects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are asking about Media URL.

In hybris, SEO friendly URL call **prettyURL**. That can be enabled by setting `media.legacy.prettyURL = true` in the **local.properties**.

With prettyURL disabled, URL looks something like this
 `/medias/fileName.jpg?context=NAYDCL3IGAZC6ZTPN4XGU4DHHI5DU4LXMVZHI6JRGIZTINI.....`

Above, `context` request paramater is base64 encoded media details.

With prettyURL enabled, URL looks something like this
 `/medias/sys_master/images/h98/h83/8804101095454/yourFileName.jpg`

Now verify you have the same value for `media.legacy.prettyURL` in all environment. By default, prettyURL is disabled(`media.legacy.prettyURL = false`).

Refer `LocalMediaWebURLStrategy` class and [help.hybris](https://help.sap.com/viewer/d0224eca81e249cb821f2cdf45a82ace/1905/en-US/8c0f64c786691014aa95f9f6b572f248.html) for more detail.

Comment: Yes, its already enabled in hac and local.properties. If I try to disable it , all images in the site are getting disabled.But has no impact in the URL.URL still comes with the same junk values.

Comment: please add full URL of your local and PROD system (remove DNS)

Comment: LOCAL :https://localhost:9002/de-de/medias/sys_master/images/images/he4/hc9/8797128622110/8797128622110.png  PRODUCTION :https://hartmann.info/de-de/medias/MoliCare-Premium-Form-normal-3-drops-symbol.png?context=bWFzdGVyfGltYWdlc3wxMTM3MHxpbWFnZS9wbmd8aW1hZ2VzL2g5Ni9oMGQvODgwMjYxNzk1MDIzOC5wbmd8ODYwM2Y1ZjdjZDcwNjRmMTA1MzU4ODNjNjY5YzJmMjg1ZTNkYmRlMTZmNDU2ZjQ2YjQxZjg1MjVjZjYxYTUzNQ

AND UAT: https://uat-molicare-com.hrt.cloud/de-de/medias/sys_master/images/images/h31/h97/8801532805150/MoliCare-Premium-Form-normal-3-drops-symbol.png

Comment: your local and UAT has prettyURL enabled as I can see `/sys_master/` in the URL but not in the Production. Also, it's value can't be changed from HAC. You have to change properties and restart the server.

Comment: Also, please check which media URL strategy being configured in your project.

Comment: I'm glad this helps you. what was the exact issue?

Comment: But some of the images are coming broken , after setting the media.legacy.prettyURL = true in Production. Although issue is not in any other environment. Any help.

Comment: Better you ask another question with more details about this Broken Image issue. Add media URL which seems broken.

Answer (score 1):

This is not junk value, it is base64 encoded text. It has unavailable characters for URL so system auto encode your value.

```
master|images|8935|image/png|images/h98/h83/8804101095454.png|c1f696f8d9dc61212d12e0829dd0a89c3a222b4312e375154fe2eac8a92520ac
```